# Can I apply an 'onchange' event by radio group

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little lost here.

I have a few radio buttons, all with the same name so they are grouped.

What I can't work out is, what would I apply the change event too? I can't get the elementsByName as this would return an array.

So, as is usually true with radio buttons, there can only be 1 selected. I want an event to trigger when it's changed.

My question is, do I have to apply an event to each radio button, or can I apply an 'onchange' event by group?

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery to help out.  You can do `$("input[name='radioname']").on("change", function() { // do something });` which will select on all of your radio buttons and attach the on change event.  You can then determine which one was clicked with `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the console to see it in action it works as requested. The trick is to target the parent then compare what was clicked and what is considered currentTarget.

```js
var fSet = document.querySelector("fieldset");
fSet.addEventListener("change", notify, false);

function notify(event) {
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    var sRadio = event.target.id;
    console.log("The selected radio is: " + sRadio);
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Radio Button onChange</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="a0" name="rGroup" checked="checked">
  <input type="radio" id="a1" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="a2" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="a3" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="a4" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="a5" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="a6" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b0" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b1" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b2" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b3" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b4" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b5" name="rGroup">
  <input type="radio" id="b6" name="rGroup">
</fieldset>
```